# make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1

Tags: ffmpeg

hi i am trying to install ffmpeg . i  choose to do it from source because i am using a vps server so i did these steps i am using git command for getting source from github after compiling i got the below result

```
#cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
#git clone --depth 1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
#cd ffmpeg
#PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264


install prefix            /root/ffmpeg_build
source path               .
C compiler                gcc
C library                 glibc
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
yasm                      yes
MMX enabled               yes
MMXEXT enabled            yes
3DNow! enabled            yes
3DNow! extended enabled   yes
SSE enabled               yes
SSSE3 enabled             yes
AVX enabled               yes
XOP enabled               yes
FMA3 enabled              yes
FMA4 enabled              yes
i686 features enabled     yes
CMOV is fast              yes
EBX available             yes
EBP available             yes
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    yes
new filter support        yes
network support           yes
threading support         pthreads
safe bitstream reader     yes
SDL support               no
opencl enabled            no
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          no
makeinfo supports HTML    no

External libraries:
iconv            libopus            libx264
libfdk_aac        libvorbis        zlib
libmp3lame        libvpx

Enabled decoders:
aac            bfi            gsm
aac_latm        bink            gsm_ms
aasc            binkaudio_dct        h261
ac3            binkaudio_rdft        h263
ac3_fixed        bintext            h263i
adpcm_4xm        bmp            h263p
adpcm_adx        bmv_audio        h264
adpcm_afc        bmv_video        hevc
adpcm_ct        brender_pix        hnm4_video
adpcm_dtk        c93            huffyuv
adpcm_ea        cavs            iac
adpcm_ea_maxis_xa    cdgraphics        idcin
adpcm_ea_r1        cdxl            idf
adpcm_ea_r2        cinepak            iff_byterun1
adpcm_ea_r3        cljr            iff_ilbm
adpcm_ea_xas        cllc            imc
adpcm_g722        comfortnoise        indeo2
adpcm_g726        cook            indeo3
adpcm_g726le        cpia            indeo4
adpcm_ima_amv        cscd            indeo5
adpcm_ima_apc        cyuv            interplay_dpcm
adpcm_ima_dk3        dca            interplay_video
adpcm_ima_dk4        dfa            jacosub
adpcm_ima_ea_eacs    dirac            jpeg2000
adpcm_ima_ea_sead    dnxhd            jpegls
adpcm_ima_iss        dpx            jv
adpcm_ima_oki        dsd_lsbf        kgv1
adpcm_ima_qt        dsd_lsbf_planar        kmvc
adpcm_ima_rad        dsd_msbf        lagarith
adpcm_ima_smjpeg    dsd_msbf_planar        libfdk_aac
adpcm_ima_wav        dsicinaudio        libopus
adpcm_ima_ws        dsicinvideo        libvorbis
adpcm_ms        dvbsub            libvpx_vp8
adpcm_sbpro_2        dvdsub            libvpx_vp9
adpcm_sbpro_3        dvvideo            loco
adpcm_sbpro_4        dxa            mace3
adpcm_swf        dxtory            mace6
adpcm_thp        eac3            mdec
adpcm_vima        eacmv            metasound
adpcm_xa        eamad            microdvd
adpcm_yamaha        eatgq            mimic
aic            eatgv            mjpeg
alac            eatqi            mjpegb
alias_pix        eightbps        mlp
als            eightsvx_exp        mmvideo
amrnb            eightsvx_fib        motionpixels
amrwb            escape124        movtext
amv            escape130        mp1
anm            evrc            mp1float
ansi            exr            mp2
ape            ffv1            mp2float
apng            ffvhuff            mp3
ass            ffwavesynth        mp3adu
asv1            fic            mp3adufloat
asv2            flac            mp3float
atrac1            flashsv            mp3on4
atrac3            flashsv2        mp3on4float
atrac3p            flic            mpc7
aura            flv            mpc8
aura2            fourxm            mpeg1video
avrn            fraps            mpeg2video
avrp            frwu            mpeg4
avs            g2m            mpegvideo
avui            g723_1            mpl2
ayuv            g729            msa1
bethsoftvid        gif            msmpeg4v1
msmpeg4v2        qcelp            twinvq
msmpeg4v3        qdm2            txd
msrle            qdraw            ulti
mss1            qpeg            utvideo
mss2            qtrle            v210
msvideo1        r10k            v210x
mszh            r210            v308
mts2            ra_144            v408
mvc1            ra_288            v410
mvc2            ralf            vb
mxpeg            rawvideo        vble
nellymoser        realtext        vc1
nuv            rl2            vc1image
on2avc            roq            vcr1
opus            roq_dpcm        vima
paf_audio        rpza            vmdaudio
paf_video        rv10            vmdvideo
pam            rv20            vmnc
pbm            rv30            vorbis
pcm_alaw        rv40            vp3
pcm_bluray        s302m            vp5
pcm_dvd            sami            vp6
pcm_f32be        sanm            vp6a
pcm_f32le        sgi            vp6f
pcm_f64be        sgirle            vp7
pcm_f64le        shorten            vp8
pcm_lxf            sipr            vp9
pcm_mulaw        smackaud        vplayer
pcm_s16be        smacker            vqa
pcm_s16be_planar    smc            wavpack
pcm_s16le        smvjpeg            webp
pcm_s16le_planar    snow            webvtt
pcm_s24be        sol_dpcm        wmalossless
pcm_s24daud        sonic            wmapro
pcm_s24le        sp5x            wmav1
pcm_s24le_planar    srt            wmav2
pcm_s32be        ssa            wmavoice
pcm_s32le        stl            wmv1
pcm_s32le_planar    subrip            wmv2
pcm_s8            subviewer        wmv3
pcm_s8_planar        subviewer1        wmv3image
pcm_u16be        sunrast            wnv1
pcm_u16le        svq1            ws_snd1
pcm_u24be        svq3            xan_dpcm
pcm_u24le        tak            xan_wc3
pcm_u32be        targa            xan_wc4
pcm_u32le        targa_y216        xbin
pcm_u8            text            xbm
pcm_zork        theora            xface
pcx            thp            xl
pgm            tiertexseqvideo        xsub
pgmyuv            tiff            xwd
pgssub            tmv            y41p
pictor            truehd            yop
pjs            truemotion1        yuv4
png            truemotion2        zero12v
ppm            truespeech        zerocodec
prores            tscc            zlib
prores_lgpl        tscc2            zmbv
ptx            tta

Enabled encoders:
a64multi        libopus            pgmyuv
a64multi5        libvorbis        png
aac            libvpx_vp8        ppm
ac3            libvpx_vp9        prores
ac3_fixed        libx264            prores_aw
adpcm_adx        libx264rgb        prores_ks
adpcm_g722        ljpeg            qtrle
adpcm_g726        mjpeg            r10k
adpcm_ima_qt        movtext            r210
adpcm_ima_wav        mp2            ra_144
adpcm_ms        mp2fixed        rawvideo
adpcm_swf        mpeg1video        roq
adpcm_yamaha        mpeg2video        roq_dpcm
alac            mpeg4            rv10
alias_pix        msmpeg4v2        rv20
amv            msmpeg4v3        s302m
ass            msvideo1        sgi
asv1            nellymoser        snow
asv2            pam            sonic
avrp            pbm            sonic_ls
avui            pcm_alaw        srt
ayuv            pcm_f32be        ssa
bmp            pcm_f32le        subrip
cinepak            pcm_f64be        sunrast
cljr            pcm_f64le        svq1
comfortnoise        pcm_mulaw        targa
dca            pcm_s16be        tiff
dnxhd            pcm_s16be_planar    tta
dpx            pcm_s16le        utvideo
dvbsub            pcm_s16le_planar    v210
dvdsub            pcm_s24be        v308
dvvideo            pcm_s24daud        v408
eac3            pcm_s24le        v410
ffv1            pcm_s24le_planar    vorbis
ffvhuff            pcm_s32be        wavpack
flac            pcm_s32le        webvtt
flashsv            pcm_s32le_planar    wmav1
flashsv2        pcm_s8            wmav2
flv            pcm_s8_planar        wmv1
g723_1            pcm_u16be        wmv2
gif            pcm_u16le        xbm
h261            pcm_u24be        xface
h263            pcm_u24le        xsub
h263p            pcm_u32be        xwd
huffyuv            pcm_u32le        y41p
jpeg2000        pcm_u8            yuv4
jpegls            pcx            zlib
libfdk_aac        pgm            zmbv
libmp3lame

Enabled hwaccels:

Enabled parsers:
aac            dvd_nav            mpegvideo
aac_latm        dvdsub            opus
ac3            flac            png
adx            gsm            pnm
bmp            h261            rv30
cavsvideo        h263            rv40
cook            h264            tak
dca            hevc            vc1
dirac            mjpeg            vorbis
dnxhd            mlp            vp3
dpx            mpeg4video        vp8
dvbsub            mpegaudio        vp9

Enabled demuxers:
aac            h261            mxg
ac3            h263            nc
act            h264            nistsphere
adf            hevc            nsv
adp            hls            nut
adx            hnm            nuv
aea            ico            ogg
afc            idcin            oma
aiff            idf            paf
amr            iff            pcm_alaw
anm            ilbc            pcm_f32be
apc            image2            pcm_f32le
ape            image2_alias_pix    pcm_f64be
apng            image2_brender_pix    pcm_f64le
aqtitle            image2pipe        pcm_mulaw
asf            image_bmp_pipe        pcm_s16be
ass            image_dpx_pipe        pcm_s16le
ast            image_exr_pipe        pcm_s24be
au            image_j2k_pipe        pcm_s24le
avi            image_jpeg_pipe        pcm_s32be
avr            image_jpegls_pipe    pcm_s32le
avs            image_pictor_pipe    pcm_s8
bethsoftvid        image_png_pipe        pcm_u16be
bfi            image_sgi_pipe        pcm_u16le
bink            image_sunrast_pipe    pcm_u24be
bintext            image_tiff_pipe        pcm_u24le
bit            image_webp_pipe        pcm_u32be
bmv            ingenient        pcm_u32le
boa            ipmovie            pcm_u8
brstm            ircam            pjs
c93            iss            pmp
caf            iv8            pva
cavsvideo        ivf            pvf
cdg            jacosub            qcp
cdxl            jv            r3d
cine            latm            rawvideo
concat            live_flv        realtext
data            lmlm4            redspark
daud            loas            rl2
dfa            lrc            rm
dirac            lvf            roq
dnxhd            lxf            rpl
dsf            m4v            rsd
dsicin            matroska        rso
dts            mgsts            rtp
dtshd            microdvd        rtsp
dv            mjpeg            sami
dxa            mlp            sap
ea            mlv            sbg
ea_cdata        mm            sdp
eac3            mmf            sdr2
epaf            mov            segafilm
ffm            mp3            shorten
ffmetadata        mpc            siff
filmstrip        mpc8            sln
flac            mpegps            smacker
flic            mpegts            smjpeg
flv            mpegtsraw        smush
fourxm            mpegvideo        sol
frm            mpl2            sox
g722            mpsub            spdif
g723_1            msnwc_tcp        srt
g729            mtv            stl
gif            mv            str
gsm            mvi            subviewer
gxf            mxf            subviewer1
sup            vc1t            webvtt
swf            vivo            wsaud
tak            vmd            wsvqa
tedcaptions        vobsub            wtv
thp            voc            wv
tiertexseq        vplayer            xa
tmv            vqf            xbin
truehd            w64            xmv
tta            wav            xwma
tty            wc3            yop
txd            webm_dash_manifest    yuv4mpegpipe
vc1

Enabled muxers:
a64            ipod            pcm_s24le
ac3            ircam            pcm_s32be
adts            ismv            pcm_s32le
adx            ivf            pcm_s8
aiff            jacosub            pcm_u16be
amr            latm            pcm_u16le
asf            lrc            pcm_u24be
asf_stream        m4v            pcm_u24le
ass            matroska        pcm_u32be
ast            matroska_audio        pcm_u32le
au            md5            pcm_u8
avi            microdvd        psp
avm2            mjpeg            rawvideo
bit            mkvtimestamp_v2        rm
caf            mlp            roq
cavsvideo        mmf            rso
crc            mov            rtp
dash            mp2            rtp_mpegts
data            mp3            rtsp
daud            mp4            sap
dirac            mpeg1system        segment
dnxhd            mpeg1vcd        smjpeg
dts            mpeg1video        smoothstreaming
dv            mpeg2dvd        sox
eac3            mpeg2svcd        spdif
f4v            mpeg2video        spx
ffm            mpeg2vob        srt
ffmetadata        mpegts            stream_segment
filmstrip        mpjpeg            swf
flac            mxf            tee
flv            mxf_d10            tg2
framecrc        null            tgp
framemd5        nut            truehd
g722            oga            uncodedframecrc
g723_1            ogg            vc1
gif            oma            vc1t
gxf            opus            voc
h261            pcm_alaw        w64
h263            pcm_f32be        wav
h264            pcm_f32le        webm
hds            pcm_f64be        webm_dash_manifest
hevc            pcm_f64le        webp
hls            pcm_mulaw        webvtt
ico            pcm_s16be        wtv
ilbc            pcm_s16le        wv
image2            pcm_s24be        yuv4mpegpipe
image2pipe

Enabled protocols:
cache            http            rtmpt
concat            httpproxy        rtp
crypto            icecast            srtp
data            md5            subfile
ffrtmphttp        mmsh            tcp
file            mmst            udp
ftp            pipe            udplite
gopher            rtmp            unix
hls

Enabled filters:
adelay            dejudder        pad
aecho            delogo            pan
aeval            deshake            perms
aevalsrc        drawbox            perspective
afade            drawgrid        phase
aformat            earwax            pixdesctest
ainterleave        ebur128            pp
allpass            edgedetect        psnr
alphaextract        elbg            pullup
alphamerge        equalizer        removelogo
amerge            extractplanes        replaygain
amix            fade            rgbtestsrc
amovie            field            rotate
anull            fieldmatch        sab
anullsink        fieldorder        scale
anullsrc        flanger            select
apad            format            sendcmd
aperms            fps            separatefields
aphaser            framepack        setdar
aresample        framestep        setfield
aselect            geq            setpts
asendcmd        gradfun            setsar
asetnsamples        haldclut        settb
asetpts            haldclutsrc        showcqt
asetrate        hflip            showinfo
asettb            highpass        showspectrum
ashowinfo        histeq            showwaves
asplit            histogram        shuffleplanes
astats            hqdn3d            signalstats
astreamsync        hqx            silencedetect
atempo            hue            silenceremove
atrim            idet            sine
avectorscope        il            smartblur
bandpass        interlace        smptebars
bandreject        interleave        smptehdbars
bass            join            split
bbox            kerndeint        spp
biquad            lenscorrection        stereo3d
blackdetect        life            super2xsai
blackframe        lowpass            swapuv
blend            lut            telecine
boxblur            lut3d            testsrc
cellauto        lutrgb            thumbnail
channelmap        lutyuv            tile
channelsplit        mandelbrot        tinterlace
codecview        mcdeint            transpose
color            mergeplanes        treble
colorbalance        movie            trim
colorchannelmixer    mp            unsharp
colorlevels        mpdecimate        uspp
colormatrix        mptestsrc        vflip
compand            negate            vignette
concat            noformat        volume
copy            noise            volumedetect
crop            null            w3fdif
cropdetect        nullsink        xbr
curves            nullsrc            yadif
dctdnoiz        overlay            zoompan
decimate        owdenoise

Enabled bsfs:
aac_adtstoasc        imx_dump_header        mp3_header_decompress
chomp            mjpeg2jpeg        noise
dump_extradata        mjpega_dump_header    remove_extradata
h264_mp4toannexb    mov2textsub        text2movsub

Enabled indevs:
dv1394            lavfi            v4l2
fbdev            oss

Enabled outdevs:
fbdev            oss            v4l2

License: nonfree and unredistributable
Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...
config.h is unchanged
config.asm is unchanged
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
```

now i am trying to run make command but getting the following  error

```
make
POD    doc/ffmpeg.pod
POD    doc/ffprobe.pod
POD    doc/ffserver.pod
POD    doc/ffmpeg-all.pod
POD    doc/ffprobe-all.pod
POD    doc/ffserver-all.pod
MAN    doc/ffmpeg.1
MAN    doc/ffprobe.1
MAN    doc/ffserver.1
MAN    doc/ffmpeg-all.1
MAN    doc/ffprobe-all.1
MAN    doc/ffserver-all.1
LD    ffmpeg_g
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(tiertexseqv.o): In function `seq_decode_op1':
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/tiertexseqv.c:111: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xsubdec.o): In function `decode_frame':
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubdec.c:121: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(xsubenc.o): In function `put_xsub_rle':
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubenc.c:45: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubenc.c:45: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/xsubenc.c:45: undefined reference to `ff_log2_tab'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(aacps.o):/root/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/libavcodec/aacps.c:196: more undefined references to `ff_log2_tab' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

can  anyone help me for it . thank you in advance

Comment: make clean && make help at all? reconfigure perhaps? also try re-checking out from git in case things have changed...is it a version issue for tiertex*?

Comment: also what is $HOME in this instance?

Comment: i have checked with make clean its the same error i am getting after going to the next step i.e make.$HOME is the root directory (~) where i  have placed my ff-mpeg build repository. i checked the git link its too working fine . but the error persist once i run the make command. no its not a version issue of tiertex.

Comment: perhaps your dependencies aren't setting up their .pc files quite right [right order] you can see the final link line with `make V=1` I would recommend disabling the offending ones (./configure --disable-XX) for now just to make it easier. GL!

Comment: Same problem on `ffmpeg 3.0` and `2.8` version on Android NDK build.